# How to `Serial.print()` "full" hexadecimal bytes?

Tags: arduino, hex, byte, println, arduino-c++

I am programming [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/) and I am trying to `Serial.print()` bytes in hexadecimal format "the my way" (keep reading for more information).

That is, by using the following code

```
byte byte1 = 0xA2;
byte byte2 = 0x05;
byte byte3 = 0x00;

Serial.println(byte1, HEX);
Serial.println(byte2, HEX);
Serial.println(byte3, HEX);
```

I get the following output in the Serial Monitor:

```
A2
5
0
```

However I would like to output the following:

```
A2
05
00
```

In words, I would like to print the "full" hexadecimal value including `0`s (`05` instead of `0` and `00` instead of `0`).

How can I make that?

Comment: Can you print them to a string in the proper format and then send that string via the serial port?

Comment: @Retired Ninja - What do you mean with "print them to a string in the proper format"? How can I make that?

Comment: `sprintf(buffer, "%02x", number); Serial.println(buffer);`

Comment: I doubt Arduino supports `sprintf`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what it supports and how, but a quick google leads me to believe sprintf is available but not for floating point numbers without some hassle.  There's also this that may work for you: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Printf

Comment: `sprintf` seems to be supported by Arduino.

Comment: and what if you want to print `0xFA2`, you will need to also print `005` and `000`?

Comment: @ladislas - The `0xFA2` byte exists?

Comment: nope, you'll need an int16_t. I was asking in case you need to change the type of what you are printing to think of a robust answer.

Answer (score 8):

Simple brute force method, is to write a routine as:

```
void p(char X) {

   if (X < 16) {Serial.print("0");}

   Serial.println(X, HEX);

}
```

And in the main code:

```
p(byte1);  // etc.
```

Comment: With the `sprintf` function (as @Retired Ninja said in a previous comment) it is more simple... why should I use your code?

Comment: @Backo, load module size.  That is, how much code does `sprintf` generate for your embedded system?  If your sketch gets too large you will have to give-up some luxuries.  But, for a small sketch whatever works is obviously acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

The lowest footprint in Memory, Code and runtime would be classic bit playing

```
byte b;
Serial.print(b>>4,  HEX);
Serial.print(b&0x0F,HEX);
```

Which is working fine on any 8bit type. For any other mask also the first line to

```
Serial.print((b>>4)&0x0F,  HEX);
```

Answer (score 3):

sorry - not enough reputation to comment but found previous answer is not fully correct. Actually, the nice light way to code it should be :

void p(**byte** X) {
   if (X < 1**0**) {Serial.print("0");}
   ...

giving the code:

```
void p(byte X) {

   if (X < 10) {Serial.print("0");}

   Serial.println(X, HEX);

}
```

And in the main code:

```
p(byte1);  // etc.
```

hope this helps

Comment: `X < 10` ? 16 maybe, but not 10;

Comment: Agreed, just modify it to test for < 0x10 and you're done :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use sprintf to print into a buffer (two chars per byte + null terminator):

```
byte byte1 = 0xA2;
byte byte2 = 0x05;
byte byte3 = 0x00;
char s[7];
sprintf(s, "%02x\n%02x\n%02x", byte1, byte2, byte3);
Serial.println(s);
```

Added new lines in between to get each on new line. About '%02x', the % means here comes formatting information, 0 means to pad with 0, 2 means pad input until 2 characters wide and x means give me this as hexadecimal.

For other formatting options see http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Converts the upper nibble of a binary value to a hexadecimal ASCII byte.
//For example, btohexa_high(0xAE) will return 'A'.
unsigned char btohexa_high(unsigned char b)
{
    b >>= 4;
    return (b>0x9u) ? b+'A'-10:b+'0';
}


//Converts the lower nibble of a binary value to a hexadecimal ASCII byte.
//  For example, btohexa_low(0xAE) will return 'E'.


unsigned char btohexa_low(unsigned char b)
{
    b &= 0x0F;
    return (b>9u) ? b+'A'-10:b+'0';
}
```

And in main code:

```
comand_mod=0xA1; //example variable
Serial.print(btohexa_high(comand_mod));
Serial.print(btohexa_low(comand_mod));
```

Answer (score 0):

wow! 7 years ago and I felt here, my answer might be useful for you (hopefully not anymore) or others looking for the answers like me.

Use "Serial.write()" to send a hex byte over serial.

All Serial.print() eg. println, printf, sprint, print will "print" your value in ASCII.