# Float variable to HEX in Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I want to convert my float variables into HEX value like 0x00466 or etc. but when I try all the things that I saw in the internet my Serial Console just turns out crazy :D like "' #gA".

I tried this code below

```
  float gyrox, gyroy, gyroz, accelx, accely, accelz, enlem, boylam, sicaklik, yukseklik, basinc;
  byte ByteArray[11];
  void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      gyrox = 1.5;
      gyroy = 2.5;
      gyroz = 2.0;
      accelx = 5.3;
      accely = 3.2;
      accelz = 6.1;
      enlem = 39.9250506;
      boylam = 32.8369756;
      sicaklik = 35.0;
      yukseklik = 103.0;
      basinc = 65.31455;

      ByteArray[0]=(gyrox,HEX);
      ByteArray[1]=(gyroy,HEX);
      ByteArray[2]=(gyroz,HEX);
      ByteArray[3]=(accelx,HEX);
      ByteArray[4]=(accely,HEX);
      ByteArray[5]=(accelz,HEX);
      ByteArray[6]=(enlem,HEX);
      ByteArray[7]=(boylam,HEX);
      ByteArray[8]=(sicaklik,HEX);
      ByteArray[9]=(yukseklik,HEX);
      ByteArray[10]=(basinc,HEX);
  }

  void loop() {
    Serial.println((char*)ByteArray);
  }
```

and the result is ""(:D) I want the result like "0x000466 or anything likte HEX value" so what should I do?

Comment: A float is stored in 4-byte in according to IEEE754, To get the LSB byte (little endian), do `Serial.print(((uint8_t*)&gyrox)[0], HEX);`. For gyrox=1.5, you should get a byte array of 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x3F, with 0x34 as the MSB.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the float to an array of bytes to get its internal representation. Then you can loop over all of the bytes and print each of them individually.

```
void printFloat(float const f)
{
  // cast the float to an array of bytes
  uint8_t const * const byteArray = (uint8_t const *)&f;
  // print the start
  Serial.print("0x");
  // loop over the bytes, sizeof(f) tells us how many bytes make up the float
  for (size_t idx = 0; idx != sizeof(f); ++idx)
  {
    // get the byte for this position
    uint8_t const b = byteArray[idx];
    // print a zero if b < 16,
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127945/how-to-serial-print-full-hexadecimal-bytes
    Serial.print(b>>4,  HEX);
    Serial.print(b&0x0F,HEX);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A float is 32 bits long (4 bytes).  You can try this:

```
float f;
Serial.print("0x"); Serial.print(*(uint32_t*)&f, HEX);
```

If you really need leading zeroes, try this:

```
void hex_print(uint32_t x)
{
    Serial.print("0x");
    for (uint32_t mask = 0x0FFFFFFFul; mask && mask > x; mask >>= 4)
        Serial.print('0');
    Serial.print(x, HEX);
}


// calling as:
float f = 123.456f;
hex_print(*(uint32_t*)&f);
```